Saving data on system shutdown from UMDF driver 2.x
I need to save some KPI data of a UMDF 2.x driver. When system is being shut down, the WriteFile API throws error ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT on the file that I'm trying to write the data to.
I'm saving data from D0Exit WDF callback function. The data is successfully saved when other operations like hibernation/disable driver are called which also trigger D0Exit callback. The only scenario wherein I'm having the issue is system-shutdown.
